# Aeon submarines - surfacing?

Tags: supreme-commander

I noticed that Aeon submarines can surface (not sure if other factions' subs can do that, too). My question is, why would I want to surface? I can't see any reason why this possibility was introduced, as then more units can attack them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are occasions when it is very useful to surface a fleet of subs to take out some shore-based object or engineer. And iirc all factions can (no idea about the Zephyr - I stopped before then).

I (when I used to play SupCom years ago) would often use them to destroy shore-based AA to allow my bombers to come over. On archipelago maps and maps with strategic islands seperate from the mainland (my favourite map - Seton's Clutch - had these) I find this feature very useful. They will not cope against concentrated land defences and ground troops such as would be found on the mainland.

Against a few ships with anti-torps then a submarine may actually be better off surfacing. They do have a plasma cannon on after all, which does reasonable damage and at reasonable range.

You can infiltrate a small fleet of 10+ subs and have a flexible force that can sink docks, take out shore defences, and most importantly *choose when to engage*.

They are not designed for prolonged heavy firefights, so use surfacing tactically and probably infrequently.

edit: I am talking about the basic subs. The poster above is correct that some have special features that require surfacing.

Answer (score 7):

Some submarines can only use their abilities on the surface, such as the T3 Strategic Missile subs and the UEF Atlantis Experimental Aircraft Carrier.

You can also sometimes use a submarine as a decoy, surfacing to draw fire and then diving to escape.

Some submarines also have anti-air/anti-surface weapons that can only fire when surfaced.

Comment: strategic missile subs can fire their cruise missiles from underwater though, iirc.

Comment: I think you can tell them to fire from underwater, but they actually surface to fire, then dive again.